# Merge two repositories with unrelated histories

Tags: git

I have two repositories with no common history. 
Repository A

- contains a subset of repository B
- almost a year earlier versions of ~ 200 Java classes of repository B have been changed.

Repository B

- contains current sources

I want to merge the sources of repo A into repo B, but neither a merge nor a rebase with -allow-unrelated histories have worked.

Comment: I did something similar (my B repository started where the A repository ended) and I described the process in this article: http://axiac.ro/blog/merging-git-repositories/

Comment: @axiac I see you merge the repose themselves but not the files in them. I don't need to keep the history of files from repo A, I only want to have them merged into existing files in repo B.

Comment: If you don't need the history of A then copy the needed files from A to B, commit them and that's all.

Comment: All those 200 files changed since then in the active repository B, too. Due to code quality reasons I'm doing a manual merge.